# Can git be configured to disable merges for particular file types?

Tags: git

For example, Apple's Interface Builder file format (`xib`) is, for all practical purposes, impossible to merge. However, because it's a text format, git will happily try to merge files of this type, and this will almost certainly result in corruption if git "succeeds".

Can git be configured to *always* fail to merge `xib` files, as it would for binary formats?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There is a great file called `.gitattributes`, which allows you to set individual properties for files in your git project. For your purposes, you would fill your `.gitattributes` with this line

```
*.xib -crlf -diff
```

This turns off line-feed correction and disables diff on this file. You can read a little more [here](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) or [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html)